# JavaScript: Toggle between 3 elements, only one is active

Tags: javascript, css

I just started with JavaScript and have a small question. On my website I have three div-elements:

```
<div id="id_1" class="class_1" onclick="itemSelected('id_1')"></div>
<div id="id_2" class="class_2" onclick="itemSelected('id_2')"></div>
<div id="id_3" class="class_3" onclick="itemSelected('id_3')"></div>
```

I added the following script to highlight the one that the user has clicked:

```
var selected = false;

function itemSelected(element) {

    if (selected == false) {
        document.getElementById(element).style.backgroundColor = "#f5b03d";
        selected = true;
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById(element).style.backgroundColor = "#99d4e5";
        selected = false;
    }
}
```

So far, this works and the user clicks an item and it gets highlighted in another color. If he clicks it again, it gets his default background color. But as soon as the user clicks one of the other items, it gets highlighted too. What I want is a single-choice functionality: As soon as the user clicks one item, the other too appear in their default background-color. Can someone help me with this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div id="id_1" class="class_0" onclick="itemSelected('id_1')"></div>
<div id="id_2" class="class_0" onclick="itemSelected('id_2')"></div>
<div id="id_3" class="class_0" onclick="itemSelected('id_3')"></div>

function itemSelected(element) {

 $('div.class_0').css({'background-color':'#99d4e5'});
document.getElementById(element).style.backgroundColor = "#f5b03d";

}
```

Change the html as above and use this jquery

Answer (score 1):

Add a shared class to each element.

When the user clicks an element use that shared class to set the default background color to all three elements.

Then use the element's unique ID to set the highlighted background color to the element that has been clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without using javascript, created a fiddle for this:
http://jsfiddle.net/6PUwz/

What I have done is, making the divs focusable by setting `tabindex="-1"` and doing the selection by the use of the css-pseudo-class `:focused`.

Check if this fits you requirements.